# Use John the Ripper to break Password Protected Zip

Tags: john-the-ripper

I installed kali linux, that comes with John the ripper. I have a password-protected zip file. I'm pretty sure the password is complex. I first convert the zip into a hash:

```
sudo zip2john FILE_LOCATION > zippedzip.txt
```

It took around 20 seconds to run that command.

I got this output:
[image]
Then I try running john on it:

```
sudo john --format=zip ZIPPEDZIP.TXT_LOCATION
```

However I keep getting an error:

```
Using default input encoding: UTF-8
No password hashes loaded (see FAQ)
```

I'm pretty new to John the ripper, but didn't I already load in a hash?

I then took a look at the FAQ but that confused me.

So next I tried to just run a wordlist through the hash

I used the following wordlist: https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/blob/master/Passwords/Common-Credentials/10-million-password-list-top-100000.txt

So I ran this:
[image]

So after trying both methods, I'm not really sure how to crack this zip.

Comment: If the password is complex, it probably won't be in the wordlist. Also, the hash was loaded when you didn't use `--format=zip`, so try your first command again without it (i.e. just `sudo john ZIPPEDZIP.TXT_LOCATION`). I guess john will recognize the hash type itself

Comment: Hi @nobody I tried doing that, and it didn't work: https://i.imgur.com/teucRDv.png

Answer (score 5):

The `zip2john` command already tells you that the output format in *PKZIP*, so you should use that format if you decide to explicitly specify it in your `john` command using the --format switch.

If you omit the --format specifier, `john` obviously recognizes the format of the hash file *correctly*.

When you read the output of your `john` command, you see that the passphrase is not found within the words contained in *10-million-password-list-top-100000.txt*.
Your challenge now is to find a wordlist suitable or big enough to actually contain the password.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so when you say the output format is PKZIP would this be the command I use: "sudo john --format=PKZIP ZIPPEDZIP.TXT_LOCATION"?

Comment: yes, but also provide a wordlist, like `--wordlist=/usr/share/wordlists/rockyou.txt` for example.

Comment: ... otherwise you'll end up in _john's incremental mode_ where it will try every possible 8-character combination which can take ages and might not deliver anything.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/iUKBUBu.png. I tried doing the  --format=PKZIP as you recommended, but I got an error. @lab9

Comment: as your hash file seems to be UTF16-encoded: Have you copied it over from a Windows system? Can you run _dos2unix_ on it and retry?

Comment: just to avoid misunderstanding: You have to use `john` against the _hash_ file (the output of _zip2john_). In the screenshot that you provided in your comment, it looks like you use `john` against the _zip file_ itself (cannot tell for sure because the filename is partially greyed out)